# How do you find inspiration as a creative person?

Tags: style, creative-writing, poetry, writers-block

Scientists and intellectuals are yet to discover the hidden mysteries of human brain. Its power and capacity is yet to be explored. Along the way, many have discovered "hacks" to get what they what their mind to be like at any particular time. We'd like to know some your mental hacks to zone in on your creativity and produce something phenomenal. References from the lives of intellectuals and creative people of past can be given if anything related is found. The findings from neuroscience which can be of help can also be shared.

(I believe to give a complete picture I should share the incident which gave rise to this question: I have written two poems on my blog: http://abstrusemusings.blogspot.com I write to express myself, to give a channel to my emotions, to say something important. And when I'm asked to just write any poem on any topic, I fail to produce the kind of quality work as I would wish to.
I am trying to compose a poem for the launch of a national campaign, and I just can't produce a mind-blowing poem that would get the readers motivated about the campaign.

How do you find inspiration? What are some of the rituals you follow to get into the creative mood ? How do you reach that meditative state?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is too subjective and "what works for you"-style to work well in our Q&A format. If you're new to the site, [take our tour](http://writers.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel of what this site is about and how it works!

Comment: @Standback I understand that this question may be opinion based but its also takes into account "facts, references, or specific expertise" as required. Facts can be given using facts of neuroscience which suggests using "anchors" (psychological concept) to get into creative state, references can be given to the lives of intellectuals of past and how they pushed their brains to do what they wanted to, specific expertise can be shared by great writers engaged in this community. I'd like to request the moderator to reconsider his decision on putting this question on hold.

Comment: I'm sorry; as written, this question is much too broad. This doesn't look to me like a neuroscience question. If you're asking a question about neuroscience, then (A) use the precise terms (for example, "inspiration" is probably very difficult to define formally; likewise, actual neuroscience rarely refers to "mental hacks"), (B) ask a *specific* question about neuroscience, and (C) probably you want to ask your question at [CogSci.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neurobiology) .

Comment: What we have here is a question which _could conceivably_ be answered using expert experience and facts, but the _typical answers it's requesting_ will be of the format "Well, what works for me personally is--", which we could have hundreds of, with none being "better" than the other and none being significant or helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I find this question quite unique.

I can relate to what your trying to say, your trying to find the right state of mind to write the best poem you've ever written. That's simple, you can't do that when your having a lot of thoughts on your mind and you can't do that because when you're trying to write the poem you have the following thought in mind at the same time " This poem has to be the best" . You're simply over-thinking to produce the best poem, I'm a little young to say "from experience" but I think I can say that whenever you want to write something (regardless if your asked to write it or if you have to write it urgently for something) do it as if it's for yourself, this may sound a little weird but for me whenever I feel like writing, the feeling is triggered by my everyday life events. It's like there's this situation or incident every time that makes me want to write something. ( I've decided to keep my writing to that because when I scheduled my writings like keeping in mind that I have to write every week...that didn't work out because it turned to be a task rather than from the inside)

I hope this helped !

Answer (score 0):

(a) Prolific writers write like other people work on their jobs: unfailingly, regularly. When you make writing a habit, then you will produce outstanding work without fail.

(b) Write about what burns on your soul. If you try to write about what you find irrelevant, your work will be irrelevant.